# How can i add a mouse click listener to a jCombobox in a jTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, listener

I created a TableColumn like this:

```
 TableColumn ColonneArticle = jTableBonCommande.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
```

I filled it from DB table named "Article"

```
 List<Article> l = new ArrayList<Article>();
   l= em.createNamedQuery("Article.findAll").getResultList();  

   TableColumn ColonneArticle = jTableBonCommande.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);

   JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
        comboBox.addItem(l.get(i).getDesignationarticle());
    }
    ColonneArticle.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));
```

Now i want to fill my jTable with selected "Article" credentials, so can i add a mouse click listener to a jCombobox in a jTable cell ?

Please Help !

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have `JTable` with a single row/column whose cell editor is a `JComboBox`, when the user selects a value from this combo box, you want to fill the table based on the selected value from the combo box?  Okay, instead of using a `JTable` for this, why not just have the `JComboBox` as a separate component and update the table based on the selected item in the combo box, using something like an `ItemListener` or `ActionListener` to detect the change...?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i want to fill each row in the table based on the selected value from the combo box in that row, so the combobox cell should appear in each row in the table

Answer (score 1):

When a cell is updated, the `TableModel#setValueAt` method is called. When this occurs for the first column, you should then load the values for the row based on the value passed to the this method

Comment: I tried ActionListener and it works just for the first item selection, when i update the selected item in the comboBox, the row data IS NOT updated :-(

Comment: Don't add any listeners to the editor itself.  You need to override the `setValueAt` method of the `TableModel`, this is when you know, without doubt, that the value is likely to have changed

Comment: or TableModelListener, but only in the case that event goes outside of JTable